# AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all' - Web scraping - Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm scraping a table from a Wikipedia page and it is showing error: attribute error. Here is my code:

```
right_table=soup.find_all('table',class_="nowraplinks collapsible autocollapse navbox-inner")

print(right_table)

print(type(right_table)) <class 'bs4.element.resultset'>
```

I want to iterate into each row, but it is showing error

```
for row in right_table.find_all('tr'):
    print(row)
```

The error is:

> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're
>   probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call
>   find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to both stackoverflow and BeautifulSoup.

The result of a find_all will be a list. For which you can not apply find_all() again as it will be going for a list.

You have to do something like (if you have only one table),

```
right_table=soup.find('table',class_="nowraplinks collapsible autocollapse navbox-inner")
for row in right_table.find_all('tr'):
    print(row)
```

or if you have multiple tables you need to add another for loop, like,

```
right_table=soup.find('table',class_="nowraplinks collapsible autocollapse navbox-inner")
for table in right_table:    
   for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        print(row)
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!